# HTML5 localstorage difficulty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, local-storage

What I was trying to do is to store in structure below inside localstorage

```
localstorage -> hash1 -> {name11, name12, name13, ...} 
             -> hash2 -> {name21, name22, name23, ...} 
              ...
```

I'm collecting names to an array then pushing like below

```
files.push(file.name);
localStorage.setItem(hash, JSON.stringify(files));
```

I thought that localstorage will be like an empty array and when I loop through localstorage I will get only my hashes. But now when I loop like below

```
for(var hash in window.localStorage){
    var files = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(hash));
    var filesHtml= [];
    $.each(files, function(i, item) {
        filesHtml.push('<li><a href="/' + hash+'/'+item + '">' + item + '</a></li>');
    });
   ...

}
```

I'm getting bunch of other data in localstorage. How can I collect my hashes like below

```
localstorage ->history -> hash1 -> {name11, name12, name13, ...} 
                       -> hash2 -> {name21, name22, name23, ...} 
                        ...
```

and create three dimensional `history` array inside localstorage so that when I loop through `history` I will get only my hashes, no other data? Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

How about using arrays ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var hashes = [];
    hashes[0] = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];

    localStorage["hashes"] = JSON.stringify(hashes);


    var restoredHashes = JSON.parse(localStorage["hashes"]); 

    for(var i = 0; i < restoredHashes.length; i++){

        var names = restoredHashes[i];

        for(var j = 0; j < names.length; j++)
        {
            $("#output").append(names[j]  + "<BR/>");
        }
    }

});
```

Edit: Redid code to actually work. Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b36rV/1/)

Edit: Added code to JSFiddle example to prove that "hashes" is persisted in localStorage. Check [JSFiddle version2](http://jsfiddle.net/b36rV/2/)

Comment: You can't use localstorage like this: `localStorage["hashes"]` Localstorage is not array, it's an object

Comment: it works. don't know what you mean. Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b36rV/1/)

Comment: Here's an article [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: I did same as you said. It worked on firefox but failed on chrome. lets chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58453/localstorage

Comment: I only use chrome. Don't know why it's not working for you in chrome. Are you using the latest version of Chrome ?

Comment: Make sure your clear your Chrome cache. When JSFiddle updates their web application, the old one is still cached in your Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you

```
for(var hash in window.localStorage){
    if(window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty(hash)){
         //Do your work
    }    
}
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't help